# Setting Code::Blocks resolution in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

I've got a small issue with menus of Codeblocks appearing too large. I suspect that is because when it starts it probably uses the system default of some sort to get it's initial resolution. However I set my x session resolution using an xrandr command like this start x -> run xrandr -> call codeblocks. This happens in other apps too like chromium, but on chromium I use a command line --force-device-scale-factor flag and it starts up fine, I couldn't find any similar flags for codeblocks, so is there a way to do it?

The ideal solution would be to set global system resolution so I wouldn't have to call xrandr at all, but I've made a few posts about it and nobody seems to know how to do that.

System: ubuntu minimal on a virtual machine, ctwm window manager, no desktop environment, start x sessions manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered but I found this solution elsewhere.

Code::Blocks uses GTK+ as it's base, so we have to modify the GTK+ themes that are available, they carry with them the font sizes and styles.

1. Download a gtk theme changer made for lxde window manager (but could be used on any window manager, I was using it on Window Maker at the time) called lxappearance

sudo apt install lxappearance

2. On the first [Widgets] page, right next to default font click the font number, that will let you select the font size.

The menus will update with the new font on restart. It's a little bit backwards of an approach, but it works.